# JQuery waypoints using multiple classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm using http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints and having 5 classes (staffmember), at the moment waypoints fires on all the classes at once when getting the first class. How to stage it so that I can add as you pass through the list?

```
<ul id="staff">
<li class="staffmember"></li>
    <li class="staffmember"></li>
    <li class="staffmember"></li>
    <li class="staffmember"></li>
    <li class="staffmember"></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('.staffmember').waypoint(function(direction) {
jQuery('.staffmember').addClass('on').next();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand you correctly try this.  It should iterate through each `.waypoint` element and add individual waypoints to each one that add the `.on` class as you scroll past them.

```
$('.staffmember').each(function() {
  $(this).waypoint(function() {
    $(this).addClass('on');
  });
});
```

Comment: `.waypoint` will iterate over every matching element, so the `each` call isn't necessary.

Comment: In Waypoints 3.0, `this` will refer to the Waypoint instance, so the addClass line turns into `$(this.element).addClass('on');`

Comment: Does not work for me. When I have four elements (with the same class) they all animate when the first one is scrolled past.. I used this code from the answer above

Comment: I have done an update to reflect @imakewebthings feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem was that you were adding the "on" class to ALL matching elements (`jQuery('.staffmember')`), instead of just to the triggering element. Waypoints already does the iteration for you, as [imakewebthings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669712/imakewebthings) points out.

So, your original jQuery should be:

```
$('.staffmember').waypoint(function(direction) {
  jQuery(this).addClass('on').next();
});
```

That should do the trick without the `each`.