# target individual instances of same type/class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I have several h2 elements on a page I'm working on and I am using waypoints.js to trigger an additional class to be added to them as they scroll into view.

Targeting each instance using ids works perfectly:

`$('#one').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $(#one).addClass('newClass');
  }, {
    offset: '80%'
})`

But I am trying to avoid using `id` on each instance as the content will likely be changed by the client on a regular basis so I would like to target only each individual `h2` that scrolls into the viewport.

My thinking was:

`$('h2').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $(this).addClass('newClass');
  }, {
    offset: '80%'
})`

but that hasn't worked.  Can someone help point me in the right direction here?

Comment: `but that hasn't worked` How that?!

Comment: Try it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/e2sn8os9/

Comment: @adeneo looks like no each loop needed but must be: `$(this.element).addClass('newClass');`  That's quite out of the way for a jQuery plugin...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060069/jquery-waypoints-using-multiple-classes#comment-37268443

Comment: @A.Wolff - yep, waypoints works without jQuery, but `context.js` is used to set the proper context when jQuery is used, and for some reason `this` is the plugins instance, while `this.element` is the elements it initialized on, and even stranger, `this.element.window` is the window the element is in. They sure are doing some strange things ?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @adeneo cool, that worked exactly how I wanted it to! If you offer that as an answer I'll select it and close this question. Thanks for the help!